# Tests fail with new generator-angular project (CoffeeScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

First I scaffolded out an angular project using the Yeoman generator-angular generator.

```
$ mkdir project && cd project
$ yo angular --coffee
...
[?] Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? Yes
[?] Would you like to include Twitter Bootstrap? Yes
[?] Would you like to use the Sass version of Twitter Bootstrap? Yes
[?] Which modules would you like to include? angular-resource.js, angular-route.js
...
```

The Karma tests with `grunt test` [don't work right out of the box](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/614), so you need to install some additional dependencies manually:

```
$ npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
$ npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
```

After this though, the tests still fail. From the errors it appears as if the coffeescript files are being interpreted as JavaScript.

```
$ grunt test
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.1 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/karl/projects/resources/test/mock/**/*.coffee" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2)]: Connected on socket W35K_wuKKVx2BweeP-F2 with id 48564140
Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
  at /Users/karl/projects/resources/app/scripts/app.coffee:7

Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
  at /Users/karl/projects/resources/app/scripts/controllers/header.coffee:4

Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
  at /Users/karl/projects/resources/app/scripts/controllers/main.coffee:4

Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
  at /Users/karl/projects/resources/test/spec/controllers/main.coffee:3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that a new generator-angular CoffeeScript project requires the `karma-coffee-preprocessor` dependency as well as a preprocessors configuration object.

I've opened [a pull request](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-karma/pull/47) for this to be fixed in the generator-karma generator but in the meantime you can fix it manually by first running the following on the command line:

```
npm install --save-dev karma-chrome-launcher karma-firefox-launcher karma-safari-launcher karma-opera-launcher karma-ie-launcher karma-jasmine karma-coffee-preprocessor
```

And then add this to `karma.conf.js`:

```
preprocessors: {
  '**/*.coffee': ['coffee']
},
```